# How can I sent multiple data types with Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE when using a shareIntent?

Tags: android, android-intent

Its pretty clear in the documentation that you can send multiple pieces of data with:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to.."));
```

but it seems, from that one line: `shareIntent.setType("image/*");` that all pieces have to be the same data type. What If I wanted to send a picture(image/jpeg) and a hashtag that should go along with in the caption (text/plain)?

How would I handle multiple kinds of content in one shareIntent? Is it possible to send 2 shareIntents to the same activity? How would I handle this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your goal is to share one picture with text, this is the code I would suggest:

```
String text = "Look at my awesome picture";
Uri pictureUri = Uri.parse("file://my_picture");
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pictureUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images..."));
```

Comment: so why is the shareIntent.setType still "image/*". Will this work when I am sending the Intent.EXTRA_TEXT?

Comment: @BigBoy1337 This will work. The easiest way to see if it works is sharing it with Gmail. You will see the text is there, and the attachment (picture).

Comment: It does work, except only on some apps? like the text record only gets added on instagram, and google inbox, but not Facebook or twitter. Any ideas why?

Comment: Facebook is difficult that way. If you want to share a picture with text on facebook, you will have to do that with the facebook sdk. I think it's called a story. I think it used to be possible, but they removed it intentionally.

Comment: It works properly with all except Facebook and Instagram.

Comment: i want to send two text fields

Comment: @Ashish most apps can't handle multiple text fields. A text message, facebook post, ... all have 1 text field. You will have to concatenate the 2 fields so it becomes 1 string. Unless you know a specific receiver which supports it. An example is the mail app, to which you can pass an email address, a subject, a content, etc. But then you will limit the number of apps the user can choose between when sharing.

Comment: @InnekeDeClippel ok

Comment: i used this method in it shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text+"\n"+TEXT);

Answer (score 10):

It's not exactly clear from the question whether you want to send multiple images or just a single image, but with an associated text.

In the first case (multiple images):

Use `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` and provide the list of uris as `EXTRA_STREAM`, as in:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
```

If it's the second case (image plus text):

Use just `ACTION_SEND` and provide *both* `EXTRA_STREAM` *and* `EXTRA_TEXT`, for example:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
```

---

If, however, you need to share streams of varying MIME types (such as both pictures and other attachments) just use a more generic MIME type, such as `*/*`. For example:

```
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
```

From the documentation of [`ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) (emphasis mine):

> Multiple types are supported, and receivers should handle mixed types
>   whenever possible. The right way for the receiver to check them is to
>   use the content resolver on each URI. *The intent sender should try to
>   put the most concrete mime type in the intent type, but it can fall
>   back to `<type>/*` or `*/*` as needed.*
>
> e.g. if you are sending `image/jpg` and `image/jpg`, the intent's type can
>   be `image/jpg`, but if you are sending `image/jpg` and `image/png`, then the
>   intent's type should be `image/*`.

This works when mixing, say, images and downloaded files.

Comment: I intend to send 1 image along with a text string. Does this mean I should use shareIntent.setType("image/*") or shareIntent.setType("*/*")

Comment: @BigBoy1337 `"image/*"` should be fine, as in the second example (unless you know the exact type of image, of course). I just wanted to point out that adding `EXTRA_TEXT` doesn't require changing the mime type.

Comment: Hi this issue in some phones `putParcelableArrayListExtra` not working as expected. It made slide show and not able to send text with images