# How can I send multiple parts of text via Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this code snippet:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
//String  shareBody = (employeeName.getText().toString());
String [] shareBody = {employeeName.getText().toString(), employeeSurname.getText().toString(), absenceType.getText().toString()};
sharingIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:myemail@gmail.com"));
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ABSENCE CARD");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
```

which successfully sends one piece of text accross. How can I include more? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464796/how-can-i-sent-multiple-data-types-with-intent-action-send-multiple-when-using-a) didn't provide me with much help. The commented line works for one but the `String` array doesn't seem to work.

Comment: it depedens, if you are going to send the strings to another app like fb or twitter, it will get it as a text but if you want to send it to another of your apps it's a better idea

Comment: Based on the snippet above, I only initialize email apps so it's going to be sent as text

Comment: why not to send a string but full of all your strings?

Comment: what do you mean? I just want to pass multiple strings at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try serializing and deserializing your string array:

```
String stringToSent = employeeName.getText().toString()+";"+ employeeSurname.getText().toString()+";"+absenceType.getText().toString();
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, stringToSent);
```

and deserialize like this:

```
String[] receivedInfo = new String[2];
receivedInfo = receivedString.split(";");
```

In your specific case, where you want to send multiple lines in an email, you can also try this: **(not tested, may need debugging)**

```
 sharingIntent.setType("text/html"); 
 sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
    Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
    .append("<html>")
    .append(employeeName.getText().toString())
    .append("<br/>")
    .append(employeeSurname.getText().toString())
    .append("<br/>")
    .append(absenceType.getText().toString())
    .append("<br/></html>").toString()    
));
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more explanation as to how to integrate this code to my code?

Comment: This is happening in an `onClick` method. Should I serialize it outside of the method and then deserialize it inside the method?

Comment: Serialize and send it in onClick, the receiver has to desirialize it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and see where it gets me

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
ArrayList<String>st= new ArrayList<String>();
st.add("string1"); // Add your text here
st.add("string 2");

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, st);
shareIntent.setType("text/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share text to.."));
```

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/sharing/send.html) out for more information

Comment: On line `shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, st);` I get "required: java.util.ArrayList< ?extends android.os.Parcel able>" on the name of the ArrayList. This is because an ArrayList is not a parcelable and I don't know how to tackle this because this method is supposed to share information and open a different app.

Comment: as you said, add the import util.ArrayList, if you require other then add it, in this case, the ArrayList is to give some string but, in the case you want just one, add a simple string